# Facebook Connect and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Is it possible to use the facebook connect option I am seeing on a ton of sites now, to allow the user to register for a WordPress account simply by using the Facebook Connect? Note, this will be used on a Wordpress site.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a programming question. A better place to ask would be at Wordpress.com or Wordpress.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to use facebook connect on wordpress site, i have done that on this site:

http://www.dirtytalk101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-facebookconnect/